# datetimePicker Column in $("#grid").kendoGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have this column in kendo grid

```
{    field: "Fecha",
      title: "Fecha Aviso",
      width: 100,
      attributes: { style: "text-align:center;" },
      template: "#= Fecha != null ? kendo.toString(Fecha, 'd/MM/yyyy') : '' #"
}
```

And this is the model  field

```
    fields: {
    Fecha:  { type: "date", format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" }, 
...
```

Now the batchEdit shows only the datePicker. How can I input dateTimePicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a dojo that shows it working for you: [custom datetime picker in batch editing](http://dojo.telerik.com/EzAqo)

all I have done is define the `editor` for the column called **Date**

```
editor: function (container, options) {
    var input = $("<input/>");
    input.attr("name", options.field);

    input.appendTo(container);

    input.kendoDateTimePicker({});
}
```

All this does is override the default editor template and applies the datetime picker control for you.

I used this [Grid API: Column Editor](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor) as a point of reference to produce this simple demo.

If you need further info let me know and I will add to the answer if I can.