# TimePicker inside kendoGrid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

First of all I'm aware of this thread : [datetimePicker Column in $("#grid").kendoGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272746/datetimepicker-column-in-grid-kendogrid)

But there might be somothinh what I'm doing wrong.

I'm getting data from api properly, so It's not an issue here.

Here is my model :

```
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        shopID: "shopID",
                        shpWorkingHourID: "shpWorkingHourID",
                        scheduleDay: "scheduleDay",
                        workStartHour: "workStartHour",
                        workEndHour: "workEndHour",
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'd like to have time picker [prefix]Hours

```
columns: [
                    {
                        title: "shop",
                        field: "shopID"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "workEndHour",
                        editor: function (container, options) {
                            console.log(options);
                            var input = $("<input/>");
                            input.attr("workEndHour", options.workEndHour);

                            input.appendTo(container);

                            input.kendoDateTimePicker({});
                        }

                    },
```

Eventhough I put console.log inside and nothing is printed. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

//EDIT :
Even if I put :
console.log('here') right after function It's not displayed as well.

```
                field: "workEndHour",
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    console.log('here');
                    console.log(options);
                    var dateString = kendo.toString(options.model.workEndHour, "HH:mm");
                    var input = $("<input value=" + dateString + " />").appendTo(container);
                    $input.datepicker();
                    input.attr("workEndHour", options.model.scheduleDay);
                },
                title: "some title"
```

//EDIT2:
The problem may be with date format ? I get this like this : 2000-01-01T00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

> Eventhough I put console.log inside and nothing is printed

This is because it's an object, you'd need to be more specific.
Here is a little more information about the options object
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editor

You can try to view/print the contents of that object by:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(options, null, 4));
```

Make sure you're properly importing all the kendo widgets:

```
 <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Then try this:

```
                                field: "workEndHour",
                                editor: function(container, options) {

                                var dateString = kendo.toString(options.model.workEndHour, "yyyy/MM/dd" );

                                var $input = $("<input value="+ dateString +" />").appendTo(container);
                                                    $input.datepicker();
                                },
                                title: "workEndHour",
                                //Specify format here. HH:mm maybe? I don't totally understand what you're trying with the hour perfix statement.
                                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
```

Here is some more information about kendo date/time formats:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.format

Comment: Thank for your effort but It doesn't work as well :/ I've edited my post with new pieco of code.

Comment: Even Input isn't created in DOM